# How to make putenv to a reentrant function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The function `putenv` is not a thread safe function, so I guess if I call `pthread_mutex_lock` before calling `putenv`, can I make `putenv` "thread safe" in this way?

I tried it but when I run it, segmentation fault came out.

Here is the code:

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t envlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void thread_func(void*arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&envlock);        
    char env[100];
    sprintf(env,"hhh=%s",(char*)arg);
    putenv(env);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&envlock);        
    return;
}

int main(){

    pthread_t thread0, thread1, thread2;

    void *shit;
    int err;
    char name0[]="thread0";
    err=pthread_create(&thread0,NULL,thread_func,(void*)name0);
    if(err!=0)
        exit(-1);


    char name1[]="thread1";
    err=pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,thread_func,(void*)name1);
    if(err!=0)
        exit(-1);


    char name2[]="thread2";
    err=pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,thread_func,(void*)name2);
    if(err!=0)
        exit(-1);

    pthread_join(thread0,&shit);
    pthread_join(thread1,&shit);
    pthread_join(thread2,&shit);

    char *hhh=getenv("hhh");
    printf("hhh is =%s",hhh);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`putenv` is reentrant in newer versions of glibc. The problem is that `putenv` does not copy the string that is given to it, and therefore you cannot base it on your stack. Try keeping your `char env[100]` in a place where it will not be destroyed at the function's end.

> The putenv() function is not required to be reentrant, and the one in
>          glibc 2.0 is not, but the glibc 2.1 version is.
>
> ...
>
> Since version 2.1.2, the glibc implementation conforms to SUSv2: the
>          pointer string given to putenv() is used.  In particular, this string
>          becomes part of the environment; changing it later will change the
>          environment.  (Thus, it is an error to call putenv() with an
>          automatic variable as the argument, then return from the calling
>          function while string is still part of the environment.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, protecting a function with a locking mechanism does not make it automatically reentrant.  Reentrancy means precisely that, that a function can be reentered again, in the middle of a call to itself, without any risk to the internal data it manages int the active call.  For that to occurr, the function must operate only on its stack frame, or be given pointers as parameters (in the stack, or in storable registers) to any externa data objects it must act upon.  This makes reentrancy possible.

Now, I'll explain one scenario where using a non-reentrant function (with the locking mechanism you propose) is not applicable:

Assume the case you have a function `f()` that is being executed, then a signal is received (or an interrupt) and the signal handler just has to make a call to `f()`.  As far as you have the function entry locked, the signal handler will be locked on entry to the function `f()`, making the handler never return, so the main program cannot continue its execution of `f()` to open the lock.  In cases (the majority) you use the same stack to handle interrupts than the one of the interrupted function (well, I know about FreeBSD using a different context for interrupt handlers, but don't know if this applies to user mode processes), no chance to unlock the lock until the handler has return, but it cannot return as far as the handler is waiting for the lock to be unlocked.  This case of reentrancy is not handled by your routine.

How can this problem be avoided.  Just avoid interrupts that call this handler when you are in the middle of the shared region (then, why to lock it?)  so interrupts are handled *after* the function call.

Of course, if you need to call it from several threads (each with it's own stack) then you need the lock after all.

## Conclusion:

The lock just avoids the reentering of `f()`, but doesn't make it reentrant.